# What are the pros and cons of unionized vs non-unionized police force

Tags: police, employment, labor-union

My question is what are the advantages and disadvantages of unionized vs non-unionized police force.

This was one of the demands which was put forward by the Black Lives Movement. Below is an article where police unions were initially disbanded.

For example [Camden NJ](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-06-04/how-camden-new-jersey-reformed-its-police-department)

> So in 2013, the mayor and city council dissolved the local PD and
>   signed an agreement for the county to provide shared services. The new
>   county force is double the size of the old one, and officers almost
>   exclusively patrol the city. (They were initially nonunion but have
>   since unionized.)

This is a complex issue thus I am just looking to understand the pros and cons of the two different police structures.

Comment: I'm sorry, but asking for "the pro's and con's" of police unions is not any different from your previous one asking for whether banning police unions "would bring positive or negative impact". When your question got closed by the community, do not repost it with minimal rewording. Fix the previously closed question instead. Or just try to understand that Politics Stack Exchange is not a good platform for discussion-oriented questions. You might want to post this on a more debate-oriented website.

Comment: @Philipp In my last question i did give my reason as to why that question should not have been closed. I had reworded this question to ask what would be the pros and cons instead of focusing banning police unions and even this has been closed. Last question was closed because it was cited as opinion based, this question was closed because why am i not changing my last question. Would deleting my last question solve the issue?.

Comment: This question is just as opinion-based as your previous one, so no. Deleting and reposting questions is no way to get around your questions getting closed for not being appropriate for this website.

Comment: But there is a case where the union was closed. Why is it opinion based if there is a precident

Comment: Both system were present with and without union. I am asking for pos and cons of these systems. How is it opinion based if both system has existed?